# android: Set clicked color of Tab to background color of a TableRow

Tags: android, tabs

I have a TabLayout. In that I have a tablelayout with dynamically added rows. 
When a TableRow is selected/clicked I want to set its background color to the Pressing or Clicked color of Tab.

I don't want to set any static color but want to use the default theme color. How to get the color info of Tablayout ?

How to handle the left and right side of the tabs ? This is what I get begore and after setting the tab_background.xml as th backgroundRsourse for all tabs :
[image: Tab bg settings]

On the left hand side, both the images are without any settings, but the right and left corners are smooth. 
On right hand side, both images are with setings, see the corners of selected tabs are just a square, they should be rounded off or smoth like the ones without any settings. 
It seems I got to use tab_selected_bar_right and tab_selected_bar_left. I have copied them to my drawable, but can't make out how do I use them. What settings to give int the xml below provided by @mudit.

Please guide me. Any help is highly appreciated. I am in a hurry.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your XML layout file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am solved with this issue. I apology for not mentioning it earlier. Sorry, I just missed out. 
@Yugandhar, Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code after adding the tabs in your java file:

( I am adding only 2 tabs, you can add this if you have more tabs)

```
TabWidget tw = getTabWidget();

View tab1View = tw.getChildAt(0);
tab1View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_background);

View tab2View = tw.getChildAt(1);
tab2View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_background);
```

Code tab_background.xml:

(put this in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg" />

    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you help me explain the above file. You said you have 2 tabs so the 1st 2 item elements must be standing for those 2 tabs - This is just my Guess. What is the 5th item element ? Please help out.

Comment: You can add "tab<n>View" objects in your class, where 'n' is the number of tabs in your tab view. Java code: View tab<n>View = tw.getChildAt(<n-1>);

Comment: I use 1.6 and it dowesn't have tab_bg, tab_selected. So I get error on all 5 item elements of xml.

Comment: you need to put 2 images named "tab_bg" and "tab_selected" which will be shown when a tab is "selected" and one when tab is in "not selected" state.

Comment: @mudit, my query is : When we select a Tab or click a button, on click we see a Orange type of color. I want to get that click color (i.e. orange default). How to get that color ?

Comment: Try using : TabWidget tw = (TabWidget)findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

Comment: Yes mudit, I go the TabWidget using the way you have mentioend. And also the colors and settings of background is changed. But the corners remain sharp and not smooth. I have uploaded image of tabs without any settings and with settings. Would be glad if yu can help with this.